# How to find out the weights of each layer of a yolov8n model?

Tags: yolo, yolov8

I need to obtain a list of layers and the number of weights per layer of a yolov8[insert variant here] model.
Is this possible? I cant seem to find documentation this specific question.

This is what I have been able to obtain but it is just a summary

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")print(model.info())

YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs
(225, 3157200, 0, 8.8575488)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'detailed=True' parameter:
`model.info(detailed=True)`